# Service doesn't support chkconfig

Tags: linux, bash

Good day,programmers. I have a problem. Please help.
I am creating a service, which must load automatically when Linux is being loaded. So,I copied the script into the directory /etc/rc.d/init.d or /etc/init.d/. But when I am preforming the command

```
chkconfig --add listOfProcesses
```

an error occurs:

```
service  listOfProcesses doesn't support chkconfig
```

Here is the content of the script. I have found the first version in the Google and have used it as a pattern.

```
#!/bin/bash
# listOfProcesses   Start the process which will show the list of processes
# chkconfig: 345 110 02
# description: This process shows current time and the list of processes
# processname: listOfProcesses
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: shows current time and the list of processes
# Description: This process shows current time and the list of processes
### END INIT INFO
# Source function library.
KIND="listOfProcesses"
    start() {
            echo -n $"Starting $KIND services: "
            daemon /home/myscript
            echo
    }   

    stop() {
            echo -n $"Shutting down $KIND services: "
            killproc /home/myscript
            echo
    }   

    restart() {
                echo -n $"Restarting $KIND services: "   
                   killproc /home/myscript
               daemon /home/myscript
               echo
    }   

    case "$1" in
      start)
              start
            ;;
      stop)
              stop
            ;;
      restart)
              restart
            ;;
      *)
            echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
            exit 1
    esac
    exit $?

exit 0;
```

The second version was made from the cron script. I found the cron script,copied it, and changed it, so I used it as the pattern.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# crond          Start/Stop the cron clock daemon.
#
# chkconfig: 2345 90 60
# description: cron is a standard UNIX program that runs user-specified \
#              programs at periodic scheduled times. vixie cron adds a \
#              number of features to the basic UNIX cron, including better \
#              security and more powerful configuration options.

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: crond crontab
# Required-Start: $local_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:  2345
# Default-Stop: 90
# Short-Description: run cron daemon
# Description: cron is a standard UNIX program that runs user-specified 
#              programs at periodic scheduled times. vixie cron adds a 
#              number of features to the basic UNIX cron, including better 
#              security and more powerful configuration options.
### END INIT INFO

rights=whoami;
root=root;
[ -f "$rights"=="$root" ] || { 
echo "this programme requires root rights";
exit 1;
}

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

start() {
  echo -n $"Starting $KIND services: ";
  daemon showListOfProcesses;
}

stop() {
 echo -n $"Shutting down $KIND services: ";
 killproc showListOfProcesses;
}

restart() {
stop
start
}

reload() {
    restart;
}

force_reload() {
    # new configuration takes effect after restart
    restart
}

case "$1" in
start)
    start
    ;;
stop)
    stop
    ;;
restart)
     restart
    ;;
reload)
    reload
    ;;
force-reload)
    force_reload
    ;;
*)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}"
    exit 2
esac
exit $?

# Show the list of processes
function showListOfProcesses {
  top > /dev/tty2;
}
```

But the situation hadn't changed. What is the problem? What is wrong in the script?

Answer (score 61):

Look at all the scripts that `chkconfig` can turn on or off in */etc/rc.d/init.d*, you'll notice that the top few comments are very important. See [How-To manage services with chkconfig and service](http://www.rpm-based.org/how-to-manage-services-with-chkconfig-and-service)

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# crond          Start/Stop the cron clock daemon.
#
# chkconfig: 2345 90 60
# description: cron is a standard UNIX program that runs user-specified \
#              programs at periodic scheduled times. vixie cron adds a \
#              number of features to the basic UNIX cron, including better \
#              security and more powerful configuration options.
```

You have a script called `listofprocesses` but to `chkconfig` this script looks like `crond` due to the 3rd line and thus it does not find any script called `listofprocesses`

You'll also most certainly want to change `chkconfig: 2345 90 60`.  Which says which run levels it should be on (in this case 2, 3, 4 and 5), what it's start order is (90) and what its kill order is (60).

You can check the service is correctly set up with `chkconfig --list listofprocesses`.

Comment: But when I change the name of the script it says that service doesn't support chkconfig. The problem has been solved. I don't know what the bash wanted, but in some time this script has worked normal

Comment: This answer does not actually point out all root causes. Yes, the crond line may have been partially to blame, but the `chkconfig: <run lvl> <start priority> <kill priority>` line has a bad value. **Start priority should be a value 0-99**.

Comment: According to https://serverfault.com/a/29801/67390 

`# chkconfig: <levels> <start> <stop>
# description: <some description>`

both lines are required.

Answer (score 23):

Just add the following line at the top:
 # chkconfig: - 99 10
it should do the trick

Comment: At the top of where?

Comment: I added it to the top of the script file. In my case this file is in `/etc/init.d/kafka`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an excellent map of the elements that need to be in an init script, to implement what chkconfig and the init subsystem is doing, and what each element actually does:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the max priority is 99, at least on CentOS 6.5, which is what I'm playing with right now.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing this issue and it was not able to call stop function during shutdown. found the solution after trying so many suggestions on net.
You need to add "touch /var/lock/subsys/" for start and rm -f /var/lock/subsys/" for stop functions in script. Stop may not work for first reboot as lock may be not available during shutdown but will start working from next reboot.

Enjoy....:)

Satya