# Service Tomcat does not support chkconfig

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee

So I am trying to get tomcat to start on server boot.  I have put a init.d script in place and scoured the net to the best of my abilities to find out why this is without any luck.

Below is my script, when I try and do chkconfig --add tomcat1 it tells me tomcat1 does not support chkconfig.  I am certain this is something very simply I am missing I just cannot find it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# Tomcat 8 start/stop/status init.d script
# Initially forked from: https://gist.github.com/valotas/1000094
# @author: Miglen Evlogiev <bash@miglen.com>
#
# Release updates:
# Updated method for gathering pid of the current proccess
# Added usage of CATALINA_BASE
# Added coloring and additional status
# Added check for existence of the tomcat user
# Added termination proccess
#chkconfig 234 20 80
#Location of JAVA_HOME (bin files)
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java

#Add Java binary files to PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

#CATALINA_HOME is the location of the bin files of Tomcat
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat1

#CATALINA_BASE is the location of the configuration files of this instance of Tomcat
export CATALINA_BASE=/usr/local/tomcat1

#TOMCAT_USER is the default user of tomcat
export TOMCAT_USER=root

#TOMCAT_USAGE is the message if this script is called without any options
TOMCAT_USAGE="Usage: $0 {\e[00;32mstart\e[00m|\e[00;31mstop\e[00m|\e[00;31mkill\e[00m|\e[00;32mstatus\e[00m|\e[00;31mrestart\e[00m}"

#SHUTDOWN_WAIT is wait time in seconds for java proccess to stop
SHUTDOWN_WAIT=20

tomcat_pid() {
        echo `ps -fe | grep $CATALINA_BASE | grep -v grep | tr -s " "|cut -d" " -f2`
}

start() {
  pid=$(tomcat_pid)
  if [ -n "$pid" ]
  then
    echo -e "\e[00;31mTomcat is already running (pid: $pid)\e[00m"
  else
    # Start tomcat
    echo -e "\e[00;32mStarting tomcat\e[00m"
    #ulimit -n 100000
    #umask 007
    #/bin/su -p -s /bin/sh $TOMCAT_USER
        if [ `user_exists $TOMCAT_USER` = "1" ]
        then
                /bin/su $TOMCAT_USER -c $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
        else
                sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
        fi
        status
  fi
  return 0
}

status(){
          pid=$(tomcat_pid)
          if [ -n "$pid" ]; then echo -e "\e[00;32mTomcat is running with pid: $pid\e[00m"
          else echo -e "\e[00;31mTomcat is not running\e[00m"
          fi
}

terminate() {
        echo -e "\e[00;31mTerminating Tomcat\e[00m"
        kill -9 $(tomcat_pid)
}

stop() {
  pid=$(tomcat_pid)
  if [ -n "$pid" ]
  then
    echo -e "\e[00;31mStoping Tomcat\e[00m"
    #/bin/su -p -s /bin/sh $TOMCAT_USER
        sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh

    let kwait=$SHUTDOWN_WAIT
    count=0;
    until [ `ps -p $pid | grep -c $pid` = '0' ] || [ $count -gt $kwait ]
    do
      echo -n -e "\n\e[00;31mwaiting for processes to exit\e[00m";
      sleep 1
      let count=$count+1;
    done

    if [ $count -gt $kwait ]; then
      echo -n -e "\n\e[00;31mkilling processes didn't stop after $SHUTDOWN_WAIT seconds\e[00m"
      terminate
    fi
  else
    echo -e "\e[00;31mTomcat is not running\e[00m"
  fi

  return 0
}

user_exists(){
        if id -u $1 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "1"
        else
                echo "0"
        fi
}

case $1 in
        start)
          start
        ;;
        stop)
          stop
        ;;
        restart)
          stop
          start
        ;;
        status)
                status
        ;;
        kill)
                terminate
        ;;
        *)
                echo -e $TOMCAT_USAGE
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: The same problem was described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133552/service-doesnt-support-chkconfig

Comment: What Linux system are you targeting?