# why chkconfig can't add my script?

Tags: bash, shell, centos, init.d, conan

Hy!

I want to add my script in init.d which starts a server at startup but when I can't add it to chkconfig.

This is a head of my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig :       2345 19 18
# Default-Start :   2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop :    0 1 6
# Short-description: Conan C/C++ Package Manager server
# description :      Conan C/C++ Package Manager server
# processname: conan_server

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions
```

And when I try to add it :

```
[root init.d]# chmod 777 conan_server
[root init.d]# chkconfig --add conan_server
-> service conan_server does not support chkconfig
```

Can you help me ? thanks :)

Comment: conan_server is not a service, it is just a regular app, I know little about chkconfig, but I'd say that services have to comply with a certain interface and have start(), stop(), etc commands. I think you might need to write a script that wraps the conan_server launch. From http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/server.html#running-from-source-linux. please check that the recommended way to use a server in production is with gunicorn

Comment: Yes I know, but gunicorn is a service and i use gunicorn in my script to start an conan server. you understand what I want to say ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Service doesn't support chkconfig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133552/service-doesnt-support-chkconfig)

Comment: No I checked before asking my question

Comment: Then by all means, please share the rest of your script.

Comment: Whatever it is that you are trying to do, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *insecure*** and you should change it to something sane (maybe `chmod 755`?) immediately.  You don't need to think about it very hard to understand why it's not a good idea to give every user on the system write access to a system control resource.

Comment: I tried this but it (755) didn't work :/

Comment: I solved the problem. It was just a problem in the comments

Comment: Was it an extra space or was anything missing? Was it covered in the link I provided above?